# jQuery Validation checkbox custom value rule

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Is it possible to check for a custom value (besides True / False) on a checkbox using the jQuery Validation plugin?

For example :

```
<input id="test" type="checkbox" name="test" value="something">
```

I cannot find a way to check for 'something' being the value. For specific reasons I cannot just use 'true' as the value.

Comment: Thanks to the answerers. But is there a specific rule to use in jQuery validation plugin, which I can't seem to find in the docs (http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/)

Comment: I have posted the answer as your requirement.

Comment: @Josh I have updated my answer http://jsfiddle.net/aJBK9/2/

Comment: Thank you to all the good answers.

Comment: Josh – mark an answer as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$('#test').attr('value');
```

[Demo JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AQd7g/)

You can use it inside custo validation method.

To declare custom rule :

```
$.validator.addMethod("myRule", function(value, element) {
    var v = element.attr('value');
    if(v === 'something') {
        return true;
    }
    return true;
}, $.validator.format('my message') );
```

To set the custom rule on a field :

```
$('#form').validate({
    rules : {
        test : {
            myRule : true
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$("#test").val()
```

or if you want to get value in change event then:

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/qsDn5/16/

```
$("#test").change(function(){
   alert(this.value); 

});
```

Comment: Thanks but how would I use this as a rule for jQuery validation plugin (http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/)

Answer (score 1):

You can add the rule using the [addMethod](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/) which then returns a boolean based on the result of a test like so:

```
// Add Custom Method
$.validator.addMethod('someTest', function(value, element){
    return 'something' === value;
}, $.validator.format('Custom Message'));

// Use Custom Method
$('#theForm').validate({
    rules: {
        checkBoxField: {
            someTest: true
        }
    ...
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6PYq7/).

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try Jquery Validation plugin,

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" />x
    <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" />y
    <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" />z
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<a id="docs" href="http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation" target="_blank">Validation Documentation</a>
```

**Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            'test[]': {
                required: true,
                maxlength: 2
                custommethod: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            'test[]': {
                required: "You must check at least 1 box",
                maxlength: "Check no more than {0} boxes"
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
            alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
            return false; // for demo
        }
    });

});
```

**Update:** http://jsfiddle.net/aJBK9/2/

Use the addMethod in jquery Validation,

```
$.validator.addMethod("custommethod", function(value, element) {
    if (value==="something"){return true;}
return false;

}, "Value must be some thing");
```

Check this demo link http://jsfiddle.net/aJBK9/1/